# how to open a new tab and observe it with html

Tags: javascript, html

i need to make a html (or js) code that opens a new tab in the browser and be able to know when the user closes it or change the url
i need it to make an ad PTC so I can pay users when they open an ad and stay there for a periode of time

Comment: Html is a markup language, it does not have the observing function

Comment: but js is capable

Answer (score 0):

If it's on the same domain you can add an event listener for [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) that compares the current time with the time the window was opened and calculates the difference.

E.g:

```js
const w = window.open("https://stackoverflow.com");
const start = new Date();
w.onbeforeunload = function() {
  const msDiff = new Date() - start;
  console.log("The new tab was closed after " + msDiff + " milliseconds");
}
```

Comment: note the same domaine that's the probleme

Comment: @IskanderSouissi What do you mean?

Comment: im making a paid to click website so the user will press a button to open a website and has to stay there for 10sec so i need to monitor his tab to see if he closes it befor 10sec

Comment: @IskanderSouissi I meant what did you mean when you said "note the same domaine that's the probleme"